# Can blender press 1, 2, and 3 to directly enter the point, line, and surface modes respectively

Tags: mesh

Can blender press 1, 2, and 3 to directly enter the point, line, and surface modes, and press tab to enter only the object mode?
It feels a bit troublesome to press a tab and then press 123 every time. 123 in object mode is not very useful.

Comment: probably with a script?